# Bake without shadows or influence from individual lights

Tags: texture-baking

I have an object with 2 materials. Rather than describe them ,here are the nodes:

Material 1:
[image]

Material 2:
[image]

The reason for the two materials is because the second is more of a decal and should appear only once in a specific location.

What I would like to achieve is to bake these 2 materials into one texture so that I can easily apply it to the whole object in Unity.

I tried baking with these settings:

[image]

This produces a completely black image. I tried a few other variations and was not able to get what I wanted. Basically, I want an image with *no* shadows, *no* lights (aside from the world lighting which is white) that I can use in Unity. I want *unity* to apply the shadows and whatnot.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Bake Type from **Combined** to **Diffuse**. This will output a shadeless texture that you can use as the Albedo map.

Repeat this process by changing the Bake Type to "Normal" if you want to bake a normal map.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I Had tried that before but also got a black texture. Is it possible that the pricipled bsdf shader does not "count" as diffuse? I would like the "base color" of the pricipled shader to come through on the baked "color" texture. My goal is to avoid having to re-create the material in unity by just applying the pre-baked textures from blender.